# Recommendations for Working Around IE9 Treewalker Filter Bug

Tags: javascript, webkit, internet-explorer-9, gecko

**Background Info**

A bug exists currently in IE9 where it thinks that the `NodeFilter` property of the `createTreeWalker` method is a callback function instead of an object containing a callback function.

In a call like this:

`document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, filter, false);`

`filter` is defined as "an object that contains a method `acceptNode`," in Webkit and Gecko; however, in IE9, there's no mention of acceptNode at all--it expects a "callback method," without that object wrapping.

**Actual Question**

So, what's the best way to work around this issue *without doing explicit browser detection*?  In some instances I need `filter` to be a method, and in others I need it to be an object containing the method.  Is there a clean way to accomplish this?  All of these browsers claim to support DOM 2.0, so I can't test on that...

**Documents - Proof of Bug**

Here's a comparison of the documentation for each:

1. [W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range-20001113/traversal.html#Traversal-Filters)
2. [Gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/treeWalker.filter)
3. [Webkit](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/WebKitDOMRef/NodeFilter_idl/Classes/NodeFilter/)
4. [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974820%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ("The NodeFilter is a callback function..." - WRONG)

Comment: Gecko has accepted a callback function as well as an object that contains an acceptNode method for almost 10 years. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=113008

Comment: That's no doubt the way to go.  The standard, however, states that it's an object that _contains_ a callback.  This comment doesn't really work toward solving my issue in any way as at the end of the day, IE9 doesn't support the standard.  So I guess... what's your point?

Comment: This was a comment, not an answer. I just wanted to point out that a callback works in at least one other browser in case it was helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I came up with one thing that works.  Open to better alternatives:

```
var filter = { acceptNode: function() {
     //do filtering...
} };

// Hackzilla.  A true W3C-compliant nodeFilter object isn't passed, and instead a "safe" one _based_ off of the real one.
var safeFilter = filter.acceptNode;
safeFilter.acceptNode = filter.acceptNode;

document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, safeFilter, false);
```

This works as nice browsers will call `.acceptNode` on the filter object, where bad ones will try and execute it immediately.

Alternatives?

Comment: You might be able to improve on that hack by writing `function filter() { /* ... */ } filter.acceptNode = filter;`

Comment: (Sorry, deleted my comment to sound like less of a jerk and be equally clear.  Replace with this one) - Unfortunately I don't have control over the instantiation of `filter`. :)

Answer (score 5):

Actually IE 9 **does** follow the spec. Read the [ECMAScript bindings section of the DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range-20001113/ecma-script-binding.html):

> **Object NodeFilter**
>
> This is an ECMAScript function reference. This method returns a Number. The parameter is a Node object.

Therefore conforming browsers (which includes current versions of all the major ones) will all accept a function as the `filter` parameter.

Comment: Interesting!  What's with the (seemingly) inconsistent definition?

Comment: There are other similar examples in DOM, such as `addEventListener()`, whose listener parameter is specified as a `EventListener`, an object that contains a `handleEvent()` method (http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener) while the ECMAScript bindings section specifies that `EventListener` should be a function reference. I imagine it's specified that way because DOM is not bound to a single programming language, and many languages (such as Java) do not support functions as first class objects, instead requiring all functions to be methods.